# Should a grammatical article be a part of a web link anchor

Tags: website-design, web, hyperlinks

When hyperlinking a noun in a webpage (or in an application), which is a part of a longer text/sentence, should a grammatical article (such as *"a"* in English) be a part of a link anchor text?

I.e., which of the following is correct from a point of view of native English speaker?

> A cat is a [mammal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mammal).

> A cat is [a mammal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mammal).

I'm not sure if this may vary with a language. In my native language, there are no articles. It may actually be a trivial question for native English speaker.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

In carefully edited text, **the choice to include the article depends on the meaning.** Examples:

> I saw a [newt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newt) yesterday, dark with blue spots. Can anybody help identify it?

— *Article not included: the reader guesses that the linked page is about newts in general.*

> I saw [a newt](https://www.wildlife.state.nh.us/images/slides/nongame-blu-spot-sal-1.jpg) yesterday, dark with blue spots. Can anybody help identify it?

—*Article included: the reader guesses that the linked page is about that specific newt.*

Sometimes it makes no difference:

> [A newt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newt) is an amphibian.
>   A [newt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newt) is an amphibian.

*—The meaning of “a newt” and “newt” in this case is the same. Regarding usability, the longer form is a bit easier to click, but also a bit more distracting.*

Comment: This is an excellent observation! I hadn't realized it, but your first two examples are exactly how I'd interpret the links. And without this answer I wouldn't have known to use that when writing.

Comment: Wait a minute, your second link is a salamander!

Comment: @DougKavendek it was turned into a newt but got better.

Comment: Good observation! Though I might've linked 'saw a newt' in the second, specific case example.

Comment: @DougKavendek Indeed. The guy asking does need help for identifying the critter.

Answer (score 19):

**Usually an article need not be a part of your link.**

Except in the cases when it makes a difference in meaning. Usually it will be a definite article, like "The Times", "El Salvador", "Al Jazeera".

Sometimes you can see Portugal city Porto spelled as **O Porto**. This is because *porto* means just "port" in Portuguese, so the city is not just Port, but "The Port".

Strictly speaking, **Los** in **Los Angeles** is also an article, but you definitely don't want to exclude it.

For indefinite articles, like *a* in English or *un/une* in French, you can treat them as a numerical "one":

> *one [mammal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mammal)*.

Rarely it needs to be together with your main word in a link.

(This is my own hack for English articles as I'm also not a native speaker).

Comment: For an example with an English-language article, *The Hague*.

Comment: If "los" was an article, it would be "los Angeles", not "Los Angeles" - it's part of the name / proper noun.  Like your example "The Times" is not "the Times".

Comment: @freedomn-m I am amused at baseball games that include "The Los Angeles Angels", which one could translate as "The The Angels Angels".  If they're playing the Yankees or Mets, from "New York, New York", so much the better.

Answer (score 8):

**As the search bots don't give importance for this stop words (the, a, an...) you don't need to hyperlink them.**

What's [Stop Words on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words):

> In computing, stop words are words which are filtered out before processing of natural language data (text). Stop words are generally the most common words in a language; there is no single universal list of stop words used by all natural language processing tools, and indeed not all tools even use such a list. **Some tools avoid removing stop words to support phrase search**.
>
> Any set of words can be chosen as the stop words for a given purpose. For some **search engines**, these are some of the most common, short function words, such as *the*, *is*, *at*, *which*, and on. In this case, stop words can cause problems when searching for phrases that include them, particularly in names such as "The Who", "The The", or "Take That". Other search engines remove some of the most common words—including lexical words, such as "want"—from a query in order to improve performance.
>
> In **SEO terminology**, stop words are the most common words that most search engines avoid, saving space and time in processing large data during crawling or indexing. This helps search engines to save space in their databases.

---

I believe that **the decision to hyperlink a word never should be related to a grammatic and yes for SEO**. Because for a user it doesn't matter if you add on the whole phrase, on click here or on a single word. For them, you must need to be clear that they have a link to another content.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's an interesting point of view. Though I was not asking for SEO reasons. I was rather asking, what is correct from user/grammatical point of view.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I believe that the decision to hyperlink a word never should be related to agrammatic and yes for SEO. Because for a user it doesn't matter if you add on the whole phrase, on click here or on a single word. For them, you must need to be clear that they have a link to another content. And of course, if this answer helps you and answer your question. You can check as the right one. And you can make the same discussion on stack overflow English https://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Could you reword this bit: "the decision to hyperlink a word never should be related to agrammatic and yes for SEO"? It's not grammatical. Do you mean "the decision to hyperlink a word should primarily be concerned about SEO, not grammar"?

Comment: Yes, @JohnKugelman, on a website I believe that the decision to hyperlink a word should primarily be concerned about SEO, not grammar.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question: If search engines *don't care* about whether you add an article to the link, then SEO does not matter for this question.

Comment: Further, I believe that websites and hyperlinks should be designed primarily for human readers, not for search engines.

Comment: And if someone thinks users don't care about what parts of the text are links, I'd ask them to consider the link to the Wikipedia page about the symbol at the end of this sentence[.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_stop) Or the link to the Wikipedia page about [the symbol at the end of this sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_stop). For me, the second one is a lot clearer and easier to click.

Comment: @JiK I completely agree. We need to think about the user and they will click where you say to click. Because of this if SEO is not important on click here you can hyperlink just the "click" or just the "here" or both or the full sentence.

Comment: @JiK though in context, shouldn't that be the [symbol at the end of this sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question_mark) vs [the symbol at the end of this sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question_mark)?  (I get your _point_)

Comment: @Baldrickk You're definitely right. See my comment to Philippe-André Lorin's answer where I had just claimed that I probably hadn't been able to realize the difference when writing. Apparently I didn't learn it even after making that comment...

Comment: An often-overlooked element of SEO is that search engines prefer sites which users develop a preference for, which they express by preferring search results directed at that site and pointing links at it from their own sites, and users prefer sites that give them a good **user experience**. It's true that you can often game the algorithms at your users' expense, but *this* site is not where those considerations should be your first resort.

Comment: I also agree with you @Will, the user always at first. But we can't forget the SEO when we are hyperlinking a word because this is one of the most important things to help your page rank.

Comment: This site is about UX, not SEO.

Comment: @TomášZato It's not the exact answer but is complementary and the information is absolutely important to take the right strategic decision. SEO is a part of the user journey that starts when the user thinks: Oh, I need fresh fish then he goes to Google and searches by fresh fish. If I position my website for the wrong word I will have the wrong customer browsing on my website. Then we need to care with it, not deep, of course.

Comment: The user experience starts on the first contact/touch with the brand and just finish on the last touch/contact.

Answer (score 6):

I would encourage including the article: not for SEO, only partially for grammar, but to increase **accessibility** .... *if* it's a mouse-based user-base or mobile app where finger-actions are most important.   Larger targets are easier to click.

However, for screen-readers, I would encourage not only not omitting the article, but (when possible) allow links to have *different first letters*.

Screen Readers such as JAWS (what I am most familiar with) allow the user to press a key-combination that brings up a Links List. (In JAWS it's INSERT+F7).  Within this list, they can arrow down to find the link they want, or they can navigate by typing the first letter until the one they want is read.  So then "**m**ammal" would be preferable to "**a** mammal" -- there are fewer ones beginning with M, so it makes navigation faster.

---

Bonus accessibility tip from a bad experience:  Don't start link or form-field names with [unicode characters](https://unicode-table.com/en/) such as ✉ or ☖ .  JAWS reads the second one as "White Shogi Piece" (that was before the word "Home" in all links on the screen) -- it was the only instance for that character, but a user can't type that!  And *every* checkbox *began* with ✉ or 📱 to indicate emails or text-messages being sent -- in tables with almost 100 entries!  (Again, screen readers use a Select-a-form-field dialog list, which would have allowed first-letter-navigation, if not for these characters.)

Comment: Interesting. Note, however, that whatever characters you use nowadays (like “a” or “7”) are Unicode characters. “Use only your target readers’ keyboard-accessible characters” may be a more usable recommendation.

Comment: Or if you use Unicode characters solely as icons, mark them up as such.

Comment: Good point.  Keyboard-accessible is always the key.  We just had to figure out what to call them in the documentation, so our team went with "Unicode graphical characters" on first reference, and then "Unicode characters" thereafter.